# How can I create a microphone app on Android?

Tags: android, microphone, speaker

I want to create a microphone app on Android that will receive sound through the microphone and play through the speakerphone but I don't know exactly what classes and services I should use.

Comment: start by breaking down your idea in sub-problems. Google the more specific questions ( eg how to use the microphone to record voice in android - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564495/how-to-use-the-microphone-on-android) work your project and post specific issues you've face here to get specific answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core of your answer is to:

A) record and store, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5699503/9415337).

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();    
String status = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if(status.equals("mounted")){
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/YOURFOLDER"; // your custom path
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP); // notice that this is the audio format, and you might want to change it to [other available audio formats][2]
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(path);
    recorder.prepare();

    // To start recording
    recorder.start();

    // To stop recording
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();

} else {
    // Handle the situation
}
```

[[Other available audio formats | 2]](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.OutputFormat)

B) Get recordings, as stated partially [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8647397/9415337). You should then show them.

```
try {
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/YOURFOLDER"; // your custom path
    File directory = new File(path);
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
} catch {
    // Handle errors (or maybe no files in the directory)
}
```

C) Play recordings, as stated partially [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9528810/9415337).

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/YOURFOLDER"+"/yourfilename.formatextension"; // your custom pathare to use the file format and directory you used when saving
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Hope this answer helps!